# Has anyone encountered this on Algolia in laravel seeding?

Tags: php, laravel, algolia, laravel-seeding

Has anyone encountered this error when seeding? I had to comment the namespaces of scout and algolia to make the seeding work. Any ideas?

[Here is a screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wnOW.jpg). [Here is a screenshot of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zndr.jpg).

Comment: It's better if you post your message here instead of linking an image. In this case, it can't connect to the host, so contact Algolia support.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry my bad. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your application ID and API key in `config/scout.php` file -

https://laravel.com/docs/master/scout#driver-prerequisites

Currently you application ID is set to: "your-application-id", that's why it cannot connect to Algolia.